# Spring MVC + JPA - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, nullpointerexception

I've lost patience. I'm trying to turn on JPA for the first time and I still get Null Pointer Exception ... I do not know what to do next. Please help.
I try to do it like in a book "Spring in action".

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.project"})
public class JpaConfig {
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("org.project.persistance");

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}
```

**Repository:**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@Repository
public class DogRepositoryImpl implements DogRepository {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManager;

    @Override
    public Dog findById(long id) {
        return entityManager.createEntityManager().find(Dog.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Dog dog) {
        entityManager.createEntityManager().persist(dog);
    }
}
```

And @Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String owner;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Please help :( 
When I tried to do it with Spring Data, it was the same.

PS: **Why after execute this code in controller tables in MySql are 'cleaning' ? **

Comment: post the exception stack trace.

Comment: also post your db cofiguration, it will be in some *.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be caused by this line:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

Once the session factory is closed, the tables will all be dropped. You can change it to `create` so that the tables will persist.

Comment: Thank You that helps me :) I just removed that line and find() works correctly, but persist() can invoke, but nothing is changing in MySql table.

Comment: In upper code, i had: import javax.persistance.Transactional;   but should be: import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; Now it works.